# passing context as argument of DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-context

it's possible to pass a context variable to a DialogFragment?

i've use this code inside dialog for passing a string:

```
public static ConfirmDialog newInstance( String f) {
    ConfirmDialog d = new ConfirmDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("FILE_NAME", f);
    d.setArguments(args);

    return d;
}
```

but i don't find any function like putString for passing context. It's possible to do that?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Your `DialogFragment` has a very handy method for getting a `Context` instance:

```
getActivity()
```

[`Fragment#getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) will return the instance of the `Activity` (which is a `Context`) that the `Fragment` is attached to. Use it after the Fragment's `onAttach()` is called. The below chart illustrates the [`Fragment` lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), as you can see, using `getActivity()` from `onCreate()` to `onDestroy()` should be a valid call.

[image]

For more information, read the [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) documentation

Answer (score 9):

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context=activity;
}
```

Need to use onAttach method : for dialog Fragment

Comment: show() method being called first and getActivity() is null. So how can i get the context then ?

Answer (score 4):

**onAttach(Activity activity)** is now deprecated,

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

use **onAttach(Context context)** instead

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this:

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.message: {
            this.startActivity(new Intent(context, Login.class));
                                 //or use getActivity() instead of context
            }
            break;
         }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        context=activity;
    }
}
```