# Item not showing inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I check everything in my code,I ask a question and do some of the modification,and also reading all the question about "Item not showing in RecyclerView",but the layout still not appear in my recyclerView.

[This is my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929053/recycleview-not-showing-in-dialogue-fragment),I attach all my code here,have 3 answer tell me,I should use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` as the parent of `RecyclerView`,so I modified the code as below

**Fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/commentFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titlebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Be the first to like this" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/comment_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentInsert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/commentField"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Add a comment" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="77dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the item which should be appear in the RecyclerView.`comment_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/commentProfilePic"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/comment_item_profile_pic"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/comment_item_profile_pic"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comment_item_profile_info_padd">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentTimestamp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/comment_item_timestamp_pad_top" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558295/recyclerview-not-showing-anything) tell that need to add this line of code `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`,I done that,this is how I `notifyDataSetChanged()` when I parse the JSON.

```
 private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {

        JSONArray commentArray = response.getJSONArray("comment");
        //get all the item in Json
        for (int i = 0; i < commentArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject commentObj = (JSONObject) commentArray.get(i);

            commentId = commentObj.getInt("comment_id");
            commenterUsername= commentObj.getString("commenter_username");
            commentBody =  commentObj.getString("comment_body");
            commenterProfileImage =  commentObj.getString("commenter_profile_image");
            commentCreatedAt = commentObj.getString("comment_created_at");

            //set all item to the Array list
            setItemToCommentArrayList(commentId,commenterUsername,commenterProfileImage,commentBody,commentCreatedAt);

        }

        // notify data changes to list adapter
        commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }catch (JSONException e){
        System.out.println("end of content");
    }

}
```

I checked,whether is something wrong when I set my adapter to the RecycleView.So i read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464294/4332049),and here is how I set my adapter

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comment, container,false);
    commentRecyclerView =(RecyclerView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.comment_recycler_view);
    commentRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    //bind the recycler view with the adapter
    commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(getActivity(),commentItems);
    final LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    commentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
    commentRecyclerView.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
```

**Here is my `CommentAdpater`** , I still didnt see any different with my another recycleview adapter.

```
public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private Context cContext;
    private List<CommentItem> commentItems;

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView commentBody,commentUsername,commentTimeStamp;
        ImageView commentProfilePic;

        //find all the view here
        MyViewHolder(final View view) {
           super(view);

            commentProfilePic = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentProfilePic);
            commentUsername = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentUsername);
            commentBody = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentBody);
            commentTimeStamp = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentTimestamp);

        }
    }

    public CommentAdapter(Context cContext, List<CommentItem> commentItems)       {
        this.cContext = cContext;
        this.commentItems = commentItems;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    //this one for make the adview inside this
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    //bind the comment item here
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View commentItemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(commentItemView);
    }

    //do all the action here
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CommentAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final CommentItem commentItem = commentItems.get(position);

        //commenter username
        holder.commentUsername.setText(commentItem.getUsername());

        //commenter profile image
        Glide
                .with(cContext)
                .load(commentItem.getCommentProfilePic())
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.commentProfilePic);


        //comment body
        holder.commentBody.setText(commentItem.getCommentBody());

        //comment timestamp
        holder.commentTimeStamp.setText(commentItem.getCommentTimeStamp());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return commentItems.size();
    }
}
```

I make sure my JSON is received in my volley Request.I log it out,is received in Volley `onResponse` .My JSON is look like this

```
  "comment":[{"comment_created_at":"2017-03-21 13:03:40","comment_id":8,"comment_body":"abc","commenter_username":"abc","profile_image_path":"http:\/\/abc\/def\/v1\/ef\/defaultmale.jpg"
```

And this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926140/json-adding-backslash-in-volley-response-called-in-a-dialogue-fragment?noredirect=1#comment72951414_42926140) I ask just tell me no need to worry about cause I using `Glide` to load my image,`Glide` will handle that

This is all the solution that tried,and still havent get it done,so what I still missing out here,in order the `comment_xml`appear to the `recyclerView` inside `Fragment.xml`? Any guide that lead me to the right direction is well-appreciated.Thanks

**UPDATE**

**Here is my `setItemToCommentArrayList()`**

```
private void setItemToCommentArrayList(int commentId, String commenterUsername, String commenterProfileImage, String commentBody, String commentCreatedAt) {
    CommentItem item = new CommentItem();
    item.setCommentId(commentId);
    item.setUsername(commenterUsername);
    item.setCommentProfilePic(commenterProfileImage);
    item.setCommentBody(commentBody);
    item.setCommentTimeStamp(commentCreatedAt);


    //save it to the comment array list
    commentItems.add(item);
}
```

**Here is my data model of Comment Item**

```
public class CommentItem {
private String username,commentBody,commentTimeStamp,commentProfilePic;
private int commentId;

public CommentItem(){
}

public CommentItem(int commentId, String username,String commentBody,String commentTimeStamp,String commentProfilePic){
    super();
    this.commentId = commentId;
    this.username = username;
    this.commentBody = commentBody;
    this.commentProfilePic= commentTimeStamp;
    this.commentTimeStamp= commentProfilePic;
}

public int getCommentId() {
    return commentId;
}

public void setCommentId(int commentId) {
    this.commentId = commentId;
}


public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getCommentBody() {
    return commentBody;
}

public void setCommentBody(String commentBody) {
    this.commentBody = commentBody;
}

public String getCommentTimeStamp() {
    return commentTimeStamp;
}

public void setCommentTimeStamp(String commentTimeStamp) {
    this.commentTimeStamp = commentTimeStamp;
}

public String getCommentProfilePic() {
    return commentProfilePic;
}

public void setCommentProfilePic(String commentProfilePic) {
    this.commentProfilePic = commentProfilePic;
}
}
```

Comment: show me your adding data into arraylistlist method    //set all item to the Array list
            setItemToCommentArrayList(commentId,commenterUsername,commenterProfileImage,commentBody,commentCreatedAt);

Comment: add this line `commentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));` and check it

Comment: @JdPrajapati ok I update my data model as well

Comment: check whether commentItems size is 0

Comment: @AnandSavjani just added the line,`context` cannot solved..

Comment: Use getActivity() instead of it

Comment: @ken show me this method setItemToCommentArrayList

Comment: @JdPrajapati ok sure.1 minute..I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to print out your `dataSet` size into `getItemCount` method of `recyclerview` -

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("Size of data:", "" +commentItems.size())
    return commentItems.size();
}
```

If it returns greater than zero - there may be a problem with your `row_item` of recyclerview. Double check your `comment_item.xml` file. Possibly try to remove `weights`.

Comment: wow..now I realize that "size of data" = 0,I just log it..how can I do next ya??

Comment: Somehow your dataSet - `commentItems` is empty. Try to figure out.

Comment: Looks like I gave you a hint! What are you waiting for? Upvote!!

Comment: Yey! Party time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Are items not showing in the cards or is the recycler view itself not showing?
If the recycler view itself is not showing, maybe the problem is inside the getItemCount the size being sent is 0.
do a check there and return 1 if size is zero.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
 if(commentItems.size() == 0) 
    return 1; 
 else
    return commentItems.size();
}
```